# How to stop syn flood attack on windows server 2003?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

How to stop syn flood attack on windows server 2003 using windows firewall or any other third party firewall?

Answer (score 2):

Check out MSDN on How to [Harden the TCP/IP Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648853.aspx)

```
Enable SYN Attack Protection
The named value to enable SYN attack protection is located beneath the registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TcpIp\Parameters.
Value name: SynAttackProtect
Recommended value: 2
Valid values: 0, 1, 2
Description: Causes TCP to adjust retransmission of SYN-ACKS. When you configure this value the connection responses timeout more quickly in the event of a SYN attack. A SYN attack is triggered when the values of TcpMaxHalfOpen or TcpMaxHalfOpenRetried are exceeded.
```

[How to harden the TCP/IP stack against denial of service attacks in Windows Server 2003](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;324270)

[Hardening the TCP/IP stack to SYN attacks](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/hardening-tcpip-stack-syn-attacks)